# Can we Configure all Release/Build definition Burn-down Charts in TFS 2015 update 3?

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2015 update 3 , I would like to see Releases/Build definitions Burn down charts on each project's on home page.

I am able to see only couple of release/build definition charts on a project, but i want to see all the release definition burndown charts on my home page. Is that possible to configure?

Here i am attaching the sample image of  couple of build/release definitions which was showing on my project dash board.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n39vb.png)

Comment: Those aren't "burn down charts". That said, I don't understand the rest of the question. You can pin a build or release chart to a dashboard. Are you having a specific issue with doing that?

Comment: I am able to pin only couple of build releases chart on dashboard. I would like to add all the build/release definition charts  to the dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally we can not pin all the build/release definitions within **only one chart/widget** to dashboard.

As a workaround we can pin each of them to the dashboard. That means select each definition >> Right click >> Add to dasboard. Please see [Add charts to a dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/add-charts-to-dashboard) for details.

You can also add more dashboards if needed, please see [Add and manage dashboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/dashboards) for details.